# how to specify kubernetes RBAC permissions for scaling a specific deployment

Tags: kubernetes, rbac, kubernetes-rbac, k8s-cluster-role

I'm trying to give a group of users permission to scale a specific set of deployments in kubernetes 1.20

I've tried using the API reference doc here: https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.20/#patch-scale-deployment-v1-apps
to set resource names like so:

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  name: kubeoperator-cr
rules:
... #irrelevant rules omitted
- apiGroups: ["apps"]
  resources:
    - /namespaces/my-namespace-name/deployments/my-deployment-name/scale
    - deployments/my-deployment-name/scale
  verbs:
    - update
    - patch
```

This doesn't work:

```
$ kubectl scale deployments -n my-namespace-name my-deployment-name --replicas 3
Error from server (Forbidden): deployments.apps "my-deployment-name" is forbidden: User "kubeoperatorrole" cannot patch resource "deployments/scale" in API group "apps" in the namespace "my-namespace-name"
```

The only way I can get the scale command to work is to grant the permission for all deployments (which is **not** what I want) like this:

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  name: kubeoperator-cr
rules:
... #irrelevant rules omitted
- apiGroups: ["apps"]
  resources:
    - deployments/scale
  verbs:
    - update
    - patch
```

```
$ kubectl scale deployments -n my-namespace-name my-deployment-name --replicas 3
deployment.apps/my-deployment-name scaled
```

What is the correct syntax for specifying a specific deployment resource by name, or is this not possible?
The deployments I'm targeting cannot be moved to an isolated namespace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`resources` isn't what you're looking for, it's `resourceNames` which has to be a specific object name like `resourceNames: [my-deployment-name]`. In general this isn't a very good approach, the expectation is that you will segment things by namespace and give them permissions in just one namespace (or two or three or whatever it is).

Comment: yup, I definitely missed that section in the docs: https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/#referring-to-resources

we're using namespace separation already on a different... layer. We could further segment it but as of now this is a special case where we just want certain developers to have permissions on a subset of applications in any given namespace.

Comment: That is a really common problem and unfortunately the RBAC layer just doesn't help that much :-( resourceNames works only when there's static object names known in advance which don't change, sounds like it will work here but beware of the solution not growing well over time.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  name: kubeoperator-cr
rules:
- apiGroups: ["apps"]
  resources:
  - deployments/scale
  resourceNames: ["my-deployment-name"]  # <-- name of your deployment here
  verbs:
  - update
  - patch
```